# glut.h error when testing glut in code blocks

Tags: c++, opengl, codeblocks, glut, pragma

When trying to build a project using glut I get an error. Not in the main.cpp but rather in the glut.h I've included.

```
#pragma comment (lib, "winmm.lib")     /* link with Windows MultiMedia lib */
#pragma comment (lib, "opengl32.lib")  /* link with Microsoft OpenGL lib */
#pragma comment (lib, "glu32.lib")     /* link with OpenGL Utility lib */
#pragma comment (lib, "glut32.lib")    /* link with Win32 GLUT lib */

#pragma warning (disable:4244)  /* Disable bogus conversion warnings. */
#pragma warning (disable:4305)  /* VC++ 5.0 version of above warning. */
```

All of these lines are the ones who show an error with the description:
Warning: ignoring #pragma warning [-Wunkown-pragmas]

It's the same error for all of the these lines.

I also get one additional error, also in the glut.h file. It's on the line:

```
typedef unsigned short wchar_t;
```

This error reads:
error: redeclaration of built in C++ type "wchar-t" [-fpermissive]

Anyone who's got an idea of how I should go about solving this issue. 
The linking seems to be fine since it realizes that the glut.h file 
exist but the glut.h is the file providing the errors.

Comment: Which OS do you work on?

Comment: Windows, using MinGW compiler.

Comment: Please stop using GLUT. Use FreeGLUT instead; it's actually been updated in the past *decade*, unlike GLUT.